# How to control the order of JavaScript functions while using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

### My Setup

```
function ajaxLoadSth(value, attribute) {

    $.post( url, value, function(response) {

        // interpreting the response
        var foobar = $('#foo') + $('.bar').find('.sth');

        // print interpretation into DOM
        container.append(foobar);

        // do some funky stuff
        doSomeFooWithDom();
        checkSomeBarHere();
        updateSomeValuesThere();

        // now call the function again with different values 

        // THIS IS WHAT MY QUESTION REFERS TO **************
        if ( true ) {
            ajaxLoadSth(newValue, newAttribute);
        }
    });
}
```

### My Problem

The function **must not** call itself before the *// do some funky stuff*-part, some DOM operation, has finished execution - **but it does**.

### My Questions

- Why is that? Is it because those "funky stuff" is located in external functions? Does this matter when it comes to synchronous execution?
- **How can I make the "itself-call" wait until the stuff above finished?**

I already thought about the functions telling that they are ready by **setting global variables** and **triggering a handler**. Each time the handler is triggered, a function is **checking** if all the vars are set correctly and **THEN doing the function call**. What about that?

Thank you so much for your time in advance!

Comment: If all your `doSomeFooWithDom` are synchronous calls, there's *no* way `ajaxLoadSth` will be getting called before them **period**. Are you sure you haven't got the `ajaxLoadSth` outside the callback (which means it's getting called before the callback?).

Answer (score 0):

Try callbacking 
eg.

```
doSomeFunkyStuff(callback){
//DO SOME FUNKY
  callback();
}

function ajaxLoadSth(value, attribute) {

    $.post( url, value, function(response) {

        // interpreting the response
        var foobar = $('#foo') + $('.bar').find('.sth');

        // print interpretation into DOM
        container.append(foobar);

        // do some funky stuff
        doSomeFunkyStuff(function(){
           ajaxLoadSth(newValue, newAttribute);
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The fact the functions are external shouldn't matter. They will execute synchronously: if you use a DOM inspector and put breakpoints inside those functions you should find they will execute in order before the AJaX call recalls itself.
2. I think the key thing here is "wait until the stuff above finished" — those functions will execute in the order you call them, but the 'finished' outcome may be asynchronous.

I wrote a plugin for dealing with this kind of stuff called [Pendant.js](https://github.com/barneycarroll/pendant.js). The idea is that you want to defer the execution of (a) given function(s) based on various dependencies: a `dependency` is a function you pass to the Pendant that gets an extra argument, `resolve`, which is a function you can call when the dependency has been met. Then you'd pass your recursive call as a `dependant`, which would only execute when all the Pendant's dependencies had been resolved.

jQuery also implements '[Promises](https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970)' out of the box, which is kind of what I want, but with a language geared to XHR which I was uncomfortable with. Having said that, it's probably far more robust (and well-documented!), so you should probably have a look at that.